# Как смонтировать папку в rw, а остальное в ro?

Tags: linux, windows, монтирование

Имеется диск D: (NTFS) и система с Linux (ext4), на одном винчестере. Я бы хотел от диска D: смонтировать лишь некоторые папки, причём в разных режимах: несколько папок в *ro*, *noexec*, несколько в *rw*, и т д. При этом на диске есть папки, которые я бы предпочел не монтировать вообще (можно, конечно, в *ro*, *noexec*, *nosuid* смонтировать, суть то одна). Решил вначале пойти обычным путём, через `mount`:

`$ sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda1 ~/filesystem`

`$ sudo mount --bind -o rw ~/filesystem/linux ~/linux`

Однако, такой способ не заработал: папка *~/linux* была смонтирована в *ro*, очевидно, из-за того, что исходная папка была на ro-разделе. А весь диск в *rw* я не хочу монтировать, дабы избежать взаимодействия с системными файлами на этом диске (*$RECYCLE.BIN*, *desktop.ini*). Мне и так ради вообще возможности монтирования диска D: пришлось вырубать 'Быстрый запуск' в Windows, да ещё в fstab дописать `remove_hiberfile`. В Android, как мне известно, реализовано что-то похожее: раздел /data смонтирован как обычно, а вот /storage - с метками nosuid,noexec и т д. - я думал реализовать, по сути, нечто то же самое с диском D:, при этом пресекая доступ к файлам Windows на нем. chmod/chattr в NTFS, как мне известно, работает не очень (поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Можно было бы пересоздать общий раздел, но во1, это можно (точнее, нужно) сделать лишь из Windows, для сохранения общего доступа, а во2, выбор файловой системы у меня слабый: NTFS и exFAT (с последним на Linux все даже ещё хуже) - единственно возможные варианты, ext-форматы не подходят по понятным причинам (также, как и btrfs, reiserfs и т д), FAT32/vFAT - имеют ограничение на размер файла, что для меня тоже недопустимо, в силу использования на диске виртуальных машин и хранения ISO образов и пары бэкапов. Можно было бы - с доступом к файлам - на Linux выкрутиться через SELinux/AppArmor, но, особенно SELinux, трудно настраивать, да ещё пришлось бы сразу настраивать под него всю систему, хоть я вообще не использую сетевых служб в Linux (типа SSH, Apache...), плюс я толком не владею навыками использования SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

назначать разные опции монтирования `ro`/`rw` для отдельных каталогов можно только при bind-монтировании **уже** примонтированной с опцией `rw` файловой системы.

какой вывод? надо сначала примонтировать файловую систему куда-нибудь в иное место, а потом оттуда bind-монтировать каталоги с разными опциями.

---

пример. допустим, файловая система уже примонтирована в каталог `1`, и мы хотим примонтировать её в каталог `2` с опцией `ro`, а каталог `1/rw` — с опцией `rw`:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/{rw,ro} 2
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── ro
│   └── rw
└── 2
$ sudo mount -o bind,ro 1 2
$ sudo mount -o bind,rw 1/rw 2/rw
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── ro
│   └── rw
└── 2
    ├── ro
    └── rw
$ find 2 -exec touch {} \;
touch: setting times of '2': Read-only file system
touch: setting times of '2/ro': Read-only file system
```

как видим, программа `touch` выдала ошибки по поводу каталогов `2` и `2/ro`, но удачно выполнилась на каталоге `2/rw`.

Comment: *aleksandr*, я уже пробовал подобное, читайте пост внимательнее. Однако, это предполагает монтирование исходного диска в rw, что для меня недопустимо. Но, если даже диск смонтировать в rw, есть папки, которые точно недопустимо оставлять в rw/без noexec/nosuid, даже в условном /mnt/d. Опять же, если бы NTFS корректно работала с chmod/chattr, или владей я SELinux, для меня это не было бы проблемой.

Comment: впрочем, можно ещё попробовать смонтировать в ```/mnt/d``` - в Рут директории, а уже папки подтянуть в ```/home/user/``` - но к ним тогда нужен корректный доступ не-рута. Однако, umask мне нельзя использовать - из-за него у меня на диске не работал git, ругался на невозможность использования команды chmod при клонировании репозитория

Comment: 1. смонтировать вы можете в `/root/куда-нибудь`. а уже биндить (`mount --bind ...`) куда вам надо: `/mnt/d` или ещё куда-нибудь. 2. `есть папки, которые точно недопустимо оставлять в rw/без noexec/nosuid` — биндите то и так, как вам нужно. 3. `доступ не-рута`/`не работал git` — не стесняйтесь задавать новые вопросы с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: 1.В таком случае боюсь потерять доступ пользователя на диск, а кидать чуть ли не 777 права на изначальную точку монтирования стирает весь смысл bind монтирования и монтирования в ```/mnt```/```/root/...```.

Comment: `боюсь потерять` — а вы проверьте: смонтируйте rw в `/root/куда/нибудь`, а потом как в ответе написано. ну а если у пользователей нет возможности писать даже при монтировании rw — так это совсем другой вопрос, который следует задать отдельно.

Comment: как вижу, все упирается в *rw* монтирование исходного диска. Да, похоже мне придётся изучать fuse-монтирование (именно оно реализовано в *Android* ```/sdcard```)

Comment: кстати, чтобы скрыть от рядовых пользователей примонтированный в rw раздел, можно (по окончании ваших bind-монтирований) смонтировать (с --bind) какой-нибудь пустой каталог поверх каталога, куда примонтировали в rw. проверьте. // или даже ещё элегантней: смонтируйте этот каталог поверх себя же, но с опцией ro.

Comment: такое себе двойное монтирование? хм, можно статью, где был бы разьяснен механизм и принцип работы такого?